# SharePoint Customize People Search

Tags: 2010

I just configured "User Profile Synchronization" service on my SP2010 box..now I want to come up with my organization Directory..my Organization offices are in different cities and one office is in different country.

I want to develop a page where I can search results by giving search criteria like 
1. Search By First  Name or Last Name
2. Search By Department
3. Search By Location
4. Search By Country

etc etc...how to develop this as I have no idea about it. Would appreciate if someone can help me out or point to any good step by step guide on net.

Thanks

Comment: Not an "answer", but a comment. Before you get too far down this path, confirm that all of that data in AD/UPS is populated and accurate. I can't tell you how many times I've seem people pull their hair out that data doesn't come up in search, only to find out that data wasn't in AD to begin with so it's not in the profile. If the data is in the profile, search should create those managed properties as long as the search account has been given the search permissions to the UPS SSA.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would probably be to learn people to use the People tab in Search Center (if you have that provisioned) maybe extending the Search Options dropdown to include Department, Location and Country.

But if you want to create seperate pages for this then on each page you need:

1. A People Search Core Results web part for displaying the result
2. A Content Editor webpart with form elements to enter the query term and post it as a "k" queryParameter with the right prefix like this:

> http://site/page.aspx?k=country:Denmark